# Как из файла views.py вызвать всплывающее окно в HTML?

Tags: html, python, django

У меня в файле views.py происходит обработка введённых данных. Как мне вызвать всплывающее окно с результатами?
Код views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FormSQL
from . import MY_FILE
err1 = "Ошибка - 1"
err2 = "Ошибка - 2"
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormSQL(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mySQLServer = form.cleaned_data['mySQLServer']
            myDataBase = form.cleaned_data['myDataBase']
            a = MY_FILE.FilingTheFieldsOfName(mySQLServer, myDataBase)

            if a == err1:
                # Вот тут во всплывающем окне вывести данные
            else:
                if a == err2:
                    # Вот тут во всплывающем окне вывести данные
                else:
                    # Вот тут во всплывающем окне вывести данные

    else:
        form = FormSQL()

    return render(request, 'html/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Код HTML, если надо:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Some</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text center">

        <form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Путь web-разработчика должен начинаться с понимания, что сайт - это на самом деле не одно приложение, а два - бэкенд и фронтенд, написанные на разных языках, работающие на разных компьютерах, в разном окружении и в разное время. Вы не можете из _представления_ вызвать окно на фронте. Можете только вернуть из него ответ, содержащий или разметку страницы или перенаправление на другую страницу.

Comment: Значит для каждого условия мне необходимо добавлять свой html файл в котором и выводить значения? @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: Либо так, либо делать один шаблон, но с более сложной логикой рендеринга.

Comment: А можно ли сделать через _return HttpResponseRedirect("<center><p>" + err1 + "</p></center>")_ ? Будет конечно не очень, но зато в том же окне. @SergeyGornostaev